# Functioning form on a cargo site?

Tags: php, html, css, email

I'm trying to create a form on a Cargo site, but they don't allow anywhere for .php files. I want the form to send an email to me upon the "submit" button being clicked. "mailto:" doesn't work, by the way.

Here's the form right now. I've tried adding an action to the form, but obviously I can't link a .php file:

```
    <form>
<ul class="form-style-1">
    <li><label>Full Name <span class="required">*</span></label><input type="text" name="field1" class="field-divided" placeholder="First"> <input type="text" name="field2" class="field-divided" placeholder="Last"></li>
    <li>
        <label>Email <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="email" name="field3" class="field-long">
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Subject</label>
        <select name="field4" class="field-select">
        <option value="Advertise">Advertise</option>
        <option value="Partnership">Partnership</option>
        <option value="General Question">General</option>
        </select>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Your Message <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <textarea name="field5" id="field5" class="field-long field-textarea"></textarea>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </li>
</ul>
</form>
```

If anyone could suggest a workaround, I'd be so grateful!

Comment: Can't you use some alternative WebApp like Google Forms or Microsoft Forms?

Comment: I can't think of any way other than using some off-site service to send the email. Neither HTML or javascript can send email.

Comment: @Lucas I would, but I want it to match the css and sit inline with the rest of the content. Thanks for the idea though!

Comment: @aynber Ah man, thanks for trying to help anyway. I might have to opt for an off-site service!

Comment: Anyber is correct. If you can't run PHP (or any other server-side scripts e.g. nodeJS or ASP.NET or anything like that) on your site then you'll need to submit the data to a 3rd-party system. You could potentially use a small cloud-based code snippet of your own, e.g. using Azure Functions or similar, without paying for an entire new site or a commercial service. Depends how you need it to work, really.